# I have a problem with installing react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I installed react-native-push-notification and I got this error. I linked it manually

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\PayReminder1\android\app\src\main\java\com\payreminder1\MainApplication.java:16: error: package com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification does not exist
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
                                            ^
C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\PayReminder1\android\app\src\main\java\com\payreminder1\MainApplication.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
            new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage()
                ^
  symbol: class ReactNativePushNotificationPackage
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in these issues? https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/728 & https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/833

Comment: Manual installation is not recommended. You can try `react-native link`

Comment: show your gradle files

Comment: I solved this error, but I have another one now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977091/suggestion-add-toolsreplace-androidappcomponentfactory-to-application

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
Actually in package.json dependencies
These two dependencies were missing even after installing

```
  "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.5.2"
```