# Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application>

Tags: react-native

I just linked react-native-push-notification and I got this error. Some help, please?

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override
```

Comment: Did u try adding that?

Comment: Can you run react-native info and post the logs